# Jquery - Change value of Input button without displaying value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have a form that I am submitting and the `value`of the input button is "View Insight."  When I submit the form using Request, I get a nasty string in the URL like Insight=View+Insight.

What I want it to say in the URL is "Insight=Confirmed".  I tried using jquery to change the value of the button and it worked but you see it changing the value in the user interface. How do I change the value of what I want without showing the user?

Here is what I have so far:

**JQUERY**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#savebtn").bind("click",function(){
        $(this).val('confirmed');
      });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="confirm4.php" method="request">
    <input type="submit" name="insights" id="savebtn" value="View Insights" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the input[type=submit] to button[type=submit] like so:

```
<form action="confirm4.php" method="request">
  <input type="hidden" name="Insight" value="Confirmed">
  <button type="submit" id="savebtn">View Insights</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Although this would work, It seems like it is a bit intrusive. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I don't see how it is intrusive. It is semantic, modern, and will work with or without the hidden attribute. Assuming the backend script doesn't require `Insight=Confirmed` You are welcome for the answer though. Heres something I urge you to look into: http://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/

Answer (score 1):

First, `.bind` is deprecated and you should be using `.on` instead.

Second, what you are looking for is

```
$("#savebtn").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //stop current submission

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.val('confirmed'); //change the value
    $this.off("click"); //unbind the handler
    $this.click(); //click the button again
});
```

Comment: Thank you Zachary, I was unaware that `.bind` was deprecated. This works perfectly.  Thanks for explaining it thoroughly.